# Go to definition in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

In VS to find a definition or root of an object we have F12 or Go to Definition option. How about XAML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you get this feature in VS2012 by default.

But there are a number of plugins that can do this

Resharper is one. It enables you to press F12 in `Binding` or `StaticResource` databound properties.

EDIT Sept 2013:

VS 2013 now comes with this feature as standard

Comment: Thanks Seb, I tried ReSharper and had heard good about it but it makes code messy. It suggests something but then adds up things which are not necessary sometimes. I guess there is no any generic method to find a source or definition (F12) the way we have in VS.

Comment: ReSharper can be completely configured and have some of it's recommendations turned off, or changed to match your own coding standard. Check out the ReShaper > Options... in the menu.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing. You can right click the name or in the name and say, "Go to Definition"
I was working off VS2010

Comment: I have tired it and since it didn't work so I brought that up here to ask others.